# Why `session_destroy()` does not work in PHP?

Tags: php, session, sessionid

I have this problem with sessions in PHP which I have never been able to comprehend!
I have the following code in a PHP file:

```
session_start();
$sid = session_id();
session_unset();
session_destroy();
echo $sid;
```

Logically every time the it should give me different session IDs cause obviously I call `session_destroy()` but it just won't kill the session. It always gives me the same session ID!
Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Well, the same ID should be ok as long as you get a new _session_. As far as I remember, you should.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Well, I need it to be different cause I'm implementing an application which authenticates users based on their session ID and I have to have full control over these things.

Comment: @Radu, Hmmmm... That's an idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me, only the following combination works perfectly to destroy a session completely:

```
session_destroy();
session_unset();
session_regenerate_id(true);
```

Edit: Did you try this:

```
<?php
session_start();
$sid = session_id();
echo $sid;
echo "<br />";

//destroy session
session_destroy();
session_unset();

//now start the new session
session_start();
session_regenerate_id(true);
$sid = session_id();
echo $sid;
?>
```

It work's perfectly.

Comment: Another users answer was to call unset($_SESSION) and Walking Man asked why its not goot to call this:
$_SESSION is a superglobal variable which is set and filled by PHP itself. You can use it to set and unset special variables, but if you destory the whole array with unset($_SESSION) you cannot anymore save variables to your session until you call $_SESSION = array(). Your session cannot be saved while $_SESSION is not an array. So it's not recommended to call unset($_SESSION) without calling $_SESSION = array() directly after this.

Answer (score 2):

[seesion_id() concept](http://theserverpages.com/php/manual/en/function.session-id.php)

refer this link.
It says **If id is specified, it will replace the current session id. session_id() needs to be called before session_start() for that purpose**.

There is a example in this states that

As of php 4.3.3 you get a notice when you start an session twice. You can use session_id() to detect if a session is already started. Before you can make a script, you must know that session_id() returns false when no session ID is known. So now we can make a script witch dectect if a session is started, and if it is not, it startes an session.

```
This is what you get then:
<?php
if(!session_id()){
 session_start();
}
?>
```